# RemoveMin in a Binary Heap Java

Tags: java

Im trying to Remove the minimum number in my Binary Heap, and I can only remove the min once but after I try to remove it again it returns 0 when It shouldn't return 0 just the Heap with the minimum number gone. I've tried to debug the problem and gotten no gain from it. If anybody can see what I'm not seeing, could you help me see the problem? Thank you in advance. Example, After i insert into the Heap from 1-6 I would have 5 6 1 2 3 4 in the Heap, after I remove min it prints out 2 3 4 5 6. But if I removeMin after that it prints out 0 instead of 3 4 5 6. Any help to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class BHeap {

public int RemoveMin(){

            while( curr != null ) {
        if( curr.key < found.key ){
            found = curr;
            p_o = prev;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.rightSibling;
    }

    this.root = merge(found.leftmostChild);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this? If I would guess, it is because you are in the same class of your Heap and you are moving the "cursor" to the end, then when you call it again it start from the end. It is just a gues since you post just this method.

Comment: Yes, Its inside my Heap class, as is my insert function, My insert fumction works correctly, would posting my while code be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe when implementing a heap (min-heap here) you should divide it into three methods in general:

-Heapify (called on an element of a heap: 1. choose the smallest element from {element, element.right, element.left}, 2. if necessary (if element is not the smallest from the three), swap the smallest of three with the element and go recursively on the element to fix the heap all way down),

-BuildHeap (Just calling Heapify appropriately),

-Extract-Min (1. swap the top element with the rightmost (last on the bottom level) element of the heap, 2. remove the already-swapped smallest element, 3. call heapify on the new top-element (just swapped) to repair the heap.

I also believe a heap is a structure mainly used as a table structure and not node-structure. "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein gives a good theoretical base for it.

As to your implementation, as far as I understand you set your found to a current root (which is the smallest element in the heap) and then search for a smaller element in the heap. You can't find any element with a smaller key than your root, or it wouldn't be a min-heap at all!

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer, I sort of see what you're saying. Also I'm reading "Advanced Data Structures" by Peter Brass which is very helpful. Its just this one minor bug that's bugging me. But im going to go off of your extractMin explanation and see where I get from there.

Comment: Another great book! As for the implementation itself - the Heapify method is a great help in maintaining the heap altogether, as it can be used universally to repair it. I see there are a few good explanations of Heapify on the Internet (it is relatively easy, I believe), I believe it is a point to start.

Comment: Yes, its a great book, I found out one thing about my code, It only throws that error of returning 0 when the min Heap is in a Heap by itself. Other than that it works flawlessly. I'm trying to figure out why that problem occurs.